# x += i is valid but x = x + i does not compile

Tags: java, type-conversion

I have the following Java code:

```
double i = 4.2;
int x = 42;

x += i;      // A valid statement
x = x + i;   // An invalid statement
```

`x += i` seems to give no errors, and sets the value of `x` to `46`, whereas `x = x + i` (correctly) gives a compilation error:

> Error:(30, 15) java: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion
>   from double to int

Clearly there is a lossy conversion in `x += i` too. Why is that statement valid?

Comment: @rgettman Well done, I couldn't find the duplicate.  SO doesn't let you search on `+=`

Comment: Neither could I. Hence, the question.

Comment: To be fair, I have the second most popular answer, and I still could find it. ;)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ok, google doesn't like `+=` either.

Comment: @PeterLawrey some love for me too! I was the one who marked it first ! :p

Comment: @StackFlowed thank you too. +1

Comment: @PeterLawrey I tried using HTML Entity Codes, or in other words, `&#43;&#61;` ... Doesn't work either. =( Apparently SO strips punctuation off of searches, like google does?